# R use value of a variable as a data frame column name

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I am guessing this is simple for an experienced used...how can I use the value of a variable to assign it as a data frame column name?  Say I have a simple data frame df as below, and a variable n that changes value based on user input.  How could I insert a new data frame column  which has as it's name the value of n?  I would also ideally like to concatenate the value of n with a simple string.  Thank you.

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1),b=c(2,2,2))

  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
```

When I simply try to assign a new column as

```
n<-15
df$n<-c(3,3,3)
```

the name of the column is simply n.

```
  a b n
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 3
3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best idea to name a column with a number, but this will work:

```
df[,paste(n)] <- c(3,3,3)
```

Comment: meh @ using `paste` for its side effect here - just use `as.character`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
 df <- cbind(df,c(3,3,3))
 names(df)[ncol(df)] <- n
```

Although, as previously pointed out, it is not good practice to give numbers as column names.